# Run a void after an async void has been completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, encryption, task

I am encrypting a file asynchronously,and after that I want to run a void to do some logic on the encrypted file. I want the compiler wait until the file has been encrypted completely.
So how can I wait for it to be completed? Have I to use "Task"?
Thanks.

```
public static async void AES_Encrypt(string path, string Password,Label lbl,ProgressBar prgBar)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open);
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (Password);
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 8, 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1 };
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();
        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged ();


                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream (ms, AES.CreateEncryptor (), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
        int read;
        long totalBytes = 0;

        while ((read = fsIn.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {

            totalBytes += read;
            double p = Math.Round((double)totalBytes * 100.0 / fsIn.Length,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven);
            lbl.Text = p.ToString ();
            prgBar.Value = (int)p;
            Application.DoEvents ();
            await cs.WriteAsync(buffer,0,read);

        }
            cs.Close();
        fsIn.Close ();


                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        AES.Clear ();
        string retFile = path + ".cte";
        File.WriteAllBytes (retFile, encryptedBytes);
        Console.WriteLine ("ok");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just use them for testing and debugging,I will remove them. I am new to using Streams. @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no way of knowing when an `async void` method has completed.  That's exactly why you should virtually never be using an `async void` method.  The method should return a `Task` so that that `Task` can be used by the caller to determine when the method has finished, what the result(s) are (if applicable) and whether it was successful, cancelled, or faulted.